# How to split 2nd element in array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

How to split 2nd value in array?

Input `[["ABCD","123,456"],["EFGH","565,565,878"]]`

Required Output `[["ABCD","123","456"],["EFGH","565","565","878"]]`

I tried `array.map(x => x[1].split(','))` but I am getting output as `[["123","456"]],["565","565","878"]]` 1st value is getting omitted. How to include 1st value also?
If I use `x.split(',')` I am getting error

> x.split is not a function

Comment: `input.map(array => array.map(str => str.split(",")).flat())`

Comment: @ChrisG ok I see solutions are better in comments :) someone else says don't answer in comments. very confusing environment. Final story I had to remove my answer.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita 99.9% of questions here are dupes, typos or rtfm. I only post an answer if a) due diligence b) actually not answered before. But again, this never happens. So I downvote/flag the question but still help the OP with a comment (since they don't know their question is bad because SO removed the rules from the question form)

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Add to this that lots of high rep users apparently have decided to just F it and post answers to obvious dupes. SO has been going down the drain for years, all we can do to keep a minimum of quality control is to keep downvoting and flagging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
input.map(([name, list])=>[name, ...list.split(',')])
```